# Jboss 7.1 ejb 2.1 custom transaction timeout configuration

Tags: jboss7.x, ejb-2.x

I'm currently trying to upgrade my web application from jboss 5.1 to jboss 7.1.1.Final

In my jboss.xml I have configured some custom ejb timeouts like the following:

```
     <session>
        <ejb-name>MSServiceEJB</ejb-name>
        <jndi-name>ejb/MSServiceEJB</jndi-name>
        <local-jndi-name>ejb/LocalMSServiceEJB</local-jndi-name>
        <method-attributes>
            <method>
                <method-name>*</method-name>
                <transaction-timeout>3600</transaction-timeout>
            </method>
        </method-attributes>
    </session>
```

jboss 7 ignores jboss.xml, where can I specify my ejb 2.1 transaction timeouts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per

[Source](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+AS5+or+AS6+to+AS7)

**Replace the jboss.xml deployment descriptor file**

> The jboss-ejb3.xml deployment descriptor replaces the jboss.xml deployment descriptor to
>   override and add to the features provided by the Java Enterprise
>   Edition (EE) defined ejb3-jar.xml deployment descriptor. The new file
>   is incompatible with jboss.xml, and the jboss.xml is now ignored in
>   deployments.

You need to create a `jboss-ejb3.xml` and put the configuration inside it.

It would look something like this:

```
<assembly-descriptor>
    <container-transaction>
        <method>
            <ejb-name>EJBName</ejb-name>
            <method-name>methodName</method-name>
            <method-intf>Local</method-intf>
        </method>
        <tx:trans-timeout>
            <tx:timeout>500</tx:timeout>
            <tx:unit>Seconds</tx:unit>
        </tx:trans-timeout>
    </container-transaction>
</assembly-descriptor>
```

You are using `EJB2.x` , so it would be better and wise to configure it in `ejb-jar.xml`

It should be created in `META-INF of the EJB jar`.

Comment: If anyone is asking himself which xlmns to set for tx: it is "urn:trans-timeout" (described [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/EJB+3+Reference+Guide))

Answer (score 3):

You can specify on the Bean method with @TransactionTimeOut annotation.

```
@TransactionTimeout(value = 10, unit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

For detailed description of how to set, please refer [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/EJB+3+Reference+Guide#EJB3ReferenceGuide-TransactionTimeout)

Maddy

Comment: This is for EJB 3, not EJB 2.