# JBoss-AS7 @TransactionTimeout: Missing Maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, transactions, jboss7.x

I'm using *JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes"* and encountering a long running method call in a `@Stateless`-Bean
which is cancelled after 5 Minutes:

```
[com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012117:
                        TransactionReaper::check timeout
```

Searching for this issue I've found some answers [Jboss 7.1 ejb 2.1 custom transaction timeout configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015280/jboss-7-1-ejb-2-1-custom-transaction-timeout-configuration/13028767#13028767) and wikis [JBoss-AS7 reference guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/EJB+3+Reference+Guide) or [JBoss Wiki](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/TransactionTimeout).

The answer seems to be simple: Annotate the method with `@TransactionTimeout`
**But**: This class is not available in my classpath!
I have a Maven project with an EAR structure and the `ejb` module has the following relevant dependencies which I use in several projects with heavy usage of EJB3:

- `org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb:jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec` (provided)
- `javax.enterprise:cdi-api` (provided)
- `org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api` (provided)
- `org.hibernate:hibernate-validator` (provided)

Which dependency is missing?

Answer (score 10):

Try this one; it took some pretty serious searching to unearth it, but it seems like it should work:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.ejb3</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-ejb3-ext-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

GitHub:

- https://github.com/jbossejb3/jboss-ejb3-ext-api
- https://github.com/jbossejb3/jboss-ejb3-ext-api/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jboss/ejb3/annotation/TransactionTimeout.java

I think that the one Petr found is the older one (originally for JBoss 4.2.x); as Thor mentioned, it doesn't include the unit parameter, and may not work with AS7.

A humble suggestion for whomever updates the [JBAS7 EJB reference guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+3+Reference+Guide); maybe the Maven details for @TransactionTimeout could be included?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
jboss-annotations-ejb3
```

It should work with this one

Comment: I'm nur sure if this is correct class (`org.jboss.annotation.ejb.TransactionTimeout`) in `jboss:jboss-annotations-ejb3:4.2.3.GA`. `@TransactionTimeout(value=1)` does not have any effect (still timeout 5min), also the described parameter _unit_ is not available.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184844/jboss-transaction-timeout-setting - try this settings in `transaction-jboss-beans.xml` and see if its working.