# Increase JTA transaction timeout limit in WildFly

Tags: java, wildfly, wildfly-8, jta

How can I increase JTA transaction timeout in WildFly?

Can be updated in `standalone.xml` as well as from Admin Console right?

Answer (score 9):

The transaction timeout can also be changed in standalone.xml directly (without using the JBoss Client). Just add this to the transactions subsystem:

```
<coordinator-environment default-timeout="1800"/>
```

Comment: For more info, see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52191_03/Platform.11-1/ATGInstallGuide/html/s0406settingthetransactiontimeoutonjb01.html).

Answer (score 5):

If you are using [Wildfly in standalone](https://developer.jboss.org/message/922597#922597), you can use Jboss Client to do this configuration:

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=transactions:write-attribute(name=default-timeout,value=500)  
{  
    "outcome" => "success",  
    "response-headers" => {  
        "operation-requires-reload" => true,  
        "process-state" => "reload-required"  
    }  
}
```

If you are using Wildfly in domain mode:

```
[domain@localhost:9990 /] /profile=full/subsystem=transactions:write-attribute(name=default-timeout,value=500)  
{  
    "outcome" => "success",  
    "result" => undefined,  
    "server-groups" => {"main-server-group" => {"host" => {"master" => {  
        "server-one" => {"response" => {  
            "outcome" => "success",  
            "response-headers" => {  
                "operation-requires-reload" => true,  
                "process-state" => "reload-required"  
            }  
        }},  
        "server-two" => {"response" => {  
            "outcome" => "success",  
            "response-headers" => {  
                "operation-requires-reload" => true,  
                "process-state" => "reload-required"  
            }  
        }}  
    }}}}  
}
```

You can also do this configurations in the Management Interface .

You can also specify the time by method or class with an annotation. But the annotation can be different among the application servers, **there is no specification** about this in J2EE. For example, [in Wildfly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15442689/2387977) the annotation is `@TransactionTimeout`:

```
@TransactionTimeout(1500)
```

And the time unit used in all cases is always in **seconds**.